# NHibernate Criterion and formula

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria

I have a setup where I have a table with two fields, FirstName and LastName. To do a search in the name, I have made a formula which contains `FirstName + " " + Lastname`.

But if I try to do the following statement:

```
Restrictions.InsensitiveLike("empl.FullNameFormula", "% " + restriction.PersonName + " %")
```

I receive the error:

"Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding."

But if I try to do an equal instead of a like it works:

```
 Restrictions.Eq("empl.FullNameFormula", "% " + restriction.PersonName + " %")
```

Is there an error with formula and trying to do an insensitive like?

I am using NHibernate Version 2.1.2.4000.

**Update:**
My stacktrace looks like this:

```
    [SqlException (0x80131904): Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +1951450
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +4849003
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +194
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +2394
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData() +33
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() +83
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) +297
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async) +954
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result) +162
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method) +32
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method) +141
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +12
   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader() +12
   NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher.ExecuteReader(IDbCommand cmd) +216
   NHibernate.Impl.MultiCriteriaImpl.GetResultsFromDatabase(IList results) +310
   NHibernate.Impl.MultiCriteriaImpl.List() +348
   NHibernate.Impl.FutureCriteriaBatch.GetResultsFrom(IMultiCriteria multiApproach) +10
   NHibernate.Impl.FutureBatch`2.GetResults() +88
   NHibernate.Impl.FutureBatch`2.get_Results() +16
   NHibernate.Impl.FutureBatch`2.GetCurrentResult(Int32 currentIndex) +52
   NHibernate.Impl.<>c__DisplayClass4`1.<GetEnumerator>b__3() +53
   NHibernate.Impl.<get_Enumerable>d__0.MoveNext() +73
   System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source) +259
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray(IEnumerable`1 source) +81
   xxx.DataAccess.PublicationRepository.Search(PublicationQuery restriction) in xxxx :197
   layouts_www_xxx.RunSearch() in xxx:100
   layouts_www_xxx.OnInit(EventArgs e) in xxxx :39
   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +333
   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +210
   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +210
   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +210
   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +210
   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +210
   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +210
   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +210
   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +210
   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +210
   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +210
   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +210
   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +210
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +378
```

Comment: What is the generated SQL for the first statement, I would find this out then run it against the database to track down your problem. I suspect a DB problem here.

Comment: also state the total rownum of the table this fragment is executed on

Comment: @Jaguar: It is going to be executed on a couple of thousands of rows, so nothing really large.

Comment: @Rippo: This is part of a much larger search, I will try to simplify it and get the sql.

Comment: A further note, does the second statement need to be wrapped around %?

Comment: @Rippo: No it was just a quick example to show that Restrictions.Eq works on the Formula and Restrictions.InsensitiveLike did not, it doesn't make sense to have % since it wouldn't find the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would see what the actual SQL is
>   being generated, you mention that this
>   is part of a much larger search...

So based on this I would either:-

a) Fire up SQL Profiler and see the SQL that is being generated and run this in SQL Management Studio

b) Download [NHProf](http://nhprof.com/) and grab the SQL and run in SQL Management Studio

c) Use Log4Net to output the generated SQL and run in SQL Management Studio

I am assuming this is a MsSQL server, if not use MySql Workbench.

This really does smell of a SQL database problem and not a NHibernate problem. Without first checking the SQL you could be barking up the wrong tree.

HTH

Comment: I didn't find the error, but I found a fix which worked, since you gave a good explanation on how to debug the error I mark your post as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have an index on FirstName that is helping the first query, while the second one is doing an expensive table scan.

Comment: meh, a couple of thousands of rows are not enough for a timeout

Comment: Post the actual exception with full stacktrace.